# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo en C con fgets() y lo almacenar en una variable?

Tags: c, variables-globales, fgets

No es el objetivo del codigo imprimir el archivo en la pantalla, `printf` está en mi código solo para depuración:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    const size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); 
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2 + 1); 
    return result;
}

int main() {
 
FILE *archivo;
char caracteres[100];
char contenido[1000] = "" ;//error: invalid initializer
char contenido_final[1000];//Estoy seguro de que mi fichero nunca tiene más de 1000 caracteres

archivo = fopen("/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt","r");
    
 if (archivo == NULL)
        exit(1);
 else {
    
  while (feof(archivo) == 0) {
     fgets(caracteres, 100, archivo);
     char* contenido_final = concat(contenido, caracteres);
     free(contenido_final);
        
        }
    
    contenido_final = contenido;//error: assignment to expression with array type
       
  }
  fclose(archivo);
  
puts("\nEl contenido de /home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt es:\n");
printf("%s\n",contenido_final);//nada

return 0;   
}
```

Mi objetivo es tener el contenido del archivo almacenado en la variable a la que se puede acceder (para poder modificarla) después de que finaliza el bucle `while`.
¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo con `fgets()` y lo almacenar en una variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para leer un archivo al completo y almacenarlo en una variable te bastan 3 líneas:

```
size_t size = fsize(archivo);
contenido_final = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
fread(contenido_final, 1, size, archivo);
```

Si aún así quieres leer por líneas, yo usaría punteros en vez de arrays, son más flexibles. Este cambio te permite usar `realloc`, lo cual te simplifica el algoritmo:

```
char * concat(char* s1, char const* s2)
{
    size_t len_s1 = (s1 != NULL) ? strlen(s1) : 0;
    size_t newSize = len_s1 + strlen(s2);
    
    char * ptr = (char*)realloc(s1, newSize);
    if ( ptr == NULL )
        return ptr;

    memcpy(ptr + len_s1, s2, strlen(s2) + 1);
    return ptr;
}
```

Este diseño te permite evitar las reservas iniciales, quedando la inicialización del buffer así:

```
char * contenido_final = NULL;
```

¿Y cómo se usa? Exactamente igual a como lo tienes en tu código:

```
contenido_final = concat(contenido_final, caracteres);
```

> `contenido_final = contenido;//error: assignment to expression with array type`

Este error es totalmente comprensible.

En tu código, `contenido_final` es un array. Un array es una estructura especial dentro del lenguaje que tiene ciertas características que lo hacen único:

- Se almacena en la pila del programa
- Su tamaño no puede variar
- No se puede reubicar en memoria (está en la pila del programa)
- Sufre una conversión implícita a puntero

La última característica es la que suele causar confusión, ya que es habitual tender a pensar que punteros y arrays son equivalentes. Al fin y al cabo tu puedes hacer lo siguiente que funcionará sin problemas:

```
char str[100] = "Hola";
char * ptr = str;
puts(ptr);
```

Sin embargo no es posible hacer el proceso inverso:

```
str = ptr; // ERROR!!!
```

Aquí podrías pensar que claro, que es obvio que lo que quieres hacer aquí es copiar el contenido de `ptr` en `str`, sin embargo, para C no es tan obvio. C es un lenguaje con reglas muy simples.

Una operación que implica coger una serie de bytes de un buffer y ponerlos en otro buffer no es una operación para nada sencilla, ya que presenta miles de interrogantes:

- ¿Cuántos datos hay que copiar? ¿Un tamaño fijo? ¿Hasta encontrar un delimitador? ¿¿??
- ¿Hay que comprobar si se excede el tamaño del buffer? ¿Cómo se hace eso?
- La memoria ¿es de acceso exclusivo o está compartida? ¿hay que bloquear algún semáforo?
- ...

Si quieres copiar los datos tienes que usar `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(contenido_final, contenido);
```

El error también se soluciona usando punteros. En este caso el compilador no copiará datos sin direcciones de memoria. Un proceso que es muy limpio, rápido y que no entraña riesgos (al menos desde el punto de vista del compilador)

Comment: Gracias. Sí se compila. Pero no estoy seguro en en qué bloque del código poner `strcpy(contenido_final, contenido);` y `contenido_final = concat(contenido_final, caracteres);`. Podría pegarlo todo juntos aquí? Es que `printf` no imprime nada y no sé que hacer.